# Fire Facebook pixel event for time spent by user

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

Would like to fire a Facebook Pixel event for users that spend a certain amount of time on a site - much like how Google Analytics does to understand who's an "engaged user". There currently doesn't appear to be a standard event for this and isn't logged automatically by the pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Can use Pixel's [trackCustom](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking#tracking-custom-events) event to track a custom event. Somewhere in the website (preferably a SPA to persist between page changes), put:

```js
// set the interval's of interest (i.e. 10 secs, 30 secs, etc...)
const msIntervals = [10000, 30000, 60000, 90000, 120000, 180000]

const timers = msIntervals.map((ms) =>
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.fbq('trackCustom', 'TimeSpent', { ms })
  }, ms)
)
```

For my own purposes I use React, so did the following in a component that never unmounts:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const msIntervals = [10000, 30000, 60000, 90000, 120000, 180000]

  const timers = msIntervals.map((ms) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.fbq('trackCustom', 'TimeSpent', { ms })
    }, ms)
  )

  return () => {
    for (const timer of timers) clearTimeout(timer)
  }
}, [])
```